# On jQuery, Metadata, and XHTML Compliance

Tags: jquery, metadata, xhtml

I want to add some jQuery functionality to our sites where one piece of markup will have a click handler which will need to cause action to happen on another piece of markup, i.e. A is a trigger for action from B.  There's no guarantee about the relative structure of A and B, so I can't rely on a jQuery selector, plus each unique A will need to relate only to its unique counterpart B.

What is the general consensus on the best way to proceed in such a circumstance?

**Option 1:** Who cares about XHTML compliance, it's overrated anyway.  We have untrained web content producers able to inject markup into our site anyway so strict XHTML compliance would be a pipe dream.  Just make up tag attributes and read their values with jQuery.

```
Example:
<div class="jquery-feature-trigger" actson="targetID">Trigger</div>
```

**Option 2:** Use attributes that look like HTML, but shouldn't really be used for that purpose.

```
Example:
<div class="jquery-feature-trigger" rel="targetID">Trigger</div>
```

**Option 3:** Use namespaces like ASP.NET 4.0 is setting out to do.

```
Example:
<div class="jquery-feature-trigger" custom:actson="targetID">Trigger</div>
```

If you want to recommend Option 3, I would appreciate a link to what is required to get this to work as I really have no idea if a DTD has to be made or how to link it in.

**Option 4:** The Stack Overflow community has a better idea...???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could investigate the [jQuery Metadata plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/metadata), which can store JSON metadata in the `class` attribute (or various other places).  Example:

```
<div class="jquery-feature-trigger { actson: 'targetID' }">Trigger</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use [`data-` attributes](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-data) for this now, in spite of XHTML compliance, like this:

```
<div class="jquery-feature-trigger" data-actson="targetID">Trigger</div>
```

These are an HTML5 feature, but don't cause any issues in HTML4/XHTML other than not being valid attributes in the validator...but no actual problems result from this.

jQuery also [has added built-in support for these since jQuery 1.4.3](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/16/jquery-143-released/) in the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) methods.

Comment: See also [HTML 5 data- Attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) by John Resig

Answer (score 1):

Is there any way that you can store the info inside the jQuery data method? Saves cluttering up the markup

For an example see here

snipplr.com/view/9715/the-jquery-data-store/

or the direct documentation

docs.jquery.com/Core/data#name

I have used it a couple of times for storing info about my elements, very useful function that doesn't seem to be know about widely!

Sorry can't post links i'm a new user :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>


  <script src="scripts/jquery/jquery-1.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--Using highlight effect to illustrate-->      
  <script src="scripts/jquery/jquery-ui-highlight.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".jquery-feature-trigger").click(function(){
           $("#target-" + $(this).attr("id")).effect("highlight", {}, 6000);

      });
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

 <div class="jquery-feature-trigger" id="1">Trigger 1</div>
 <div class="jquery-feature-trigger" id="2">Trigger 2</div>
 <div class="jquery-feature-trigger" id="3">Trigger 3</div>
 <div class="jquery-feature-target" id="target-1">Target 1</div>
 <div class="jquery-feature-target" id="target-2">Target 2</div>
 <div class="jquery-feature-target" id="target-3">Target 3</div>   

</body>
</html>
```

So I have decided to give the target divs the id  "target-x" and give the trigger divs the id "x". This way, when you click on trigger x it affects target "target-x".

Notice the line that goes

```
$("#target-" + $(this).attr("id"))
```

its at that point that you get the id of the clicked div and concatenate it onto "target-" and that becomes the id of the target div.

Answer (score 0):

And what about putting inside your div hidden inputs with appropriate names and ids? This way you keep XHTML clear.
So you will use like that:

```
$( "div_name").find( "hidden_input_name").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you're doing, but would it possible to make the trigger be an anchor tag and then give the target an id? Like this:

```
<a href="#target1">Trigger 1</a>
<div id="target1">Target 1</div>
```

Then you could use jQuery to find the id of the target by looking at the href attribute.

If trigger 1 hides or shows target 1 or scrolls down to it, this method would have the added benefit of still doing something if JavaScript was disabled.